# dirname with folders that contain ~

Tags: php, dirname

I am trying to do a URL parser for my project, something very simple that gets an URL like you would enter it in a browser and convert it into a valid URL, once that is done parse such URL and grab all the images with full paths.

I was able to "fix" the user entered URL and pre-pend the http when needed, remove the last / on domain only (`http://www.domain.com/ become http://www.domain.com but http://www.domain.com/test/ stays unchanged).

The problem that I am having is dirname is parsing the path of certain folders.
my code looks something like this:

```
<?php
$url         = 'www.domain.com/~folder/';  //This is a variable that changes often
$url         = $this->fix_url($url);  //$url is now http://www.domain.com/~folder/
$url_image   = 'image.png';
$parse       = parse_url($url);
$dir         = (isset($parse['path'])?dirname($parse['path']):'');
$ret         = 'http://'.$parse['host'].$dir.'/'.$url_image;
var_dump($parse, $dir, $ret);
?>
```

The way I was able to go around the problem is with this code that I use to find `$dir`

```
<?php
$path    = (isset($parse['path'])?$parse['path']:'/');
$tmp     = explode('/', $path);
if(is_array($tmp) && count($tmp) > 0){
    array_pop($tmp);
}
$dir = implode('/', $tmp);
?>
```

But there must be a better way

Comment: how is parse_url() not working for you? what in its `'path'` result is not accurate?

Comment: `path` is correct, the problem is the `dirname('/~folder/')` that returns `/` instead than `/~folder/`